# SSLServerSocket and SSLSocket handshake exception in Java

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, serversocket

I have a client/server architecture using SSLSockets in Java. I am getting handshake Exceptions. I executed the client application and server application from the terminal with the debug option to capture the issues with the SSL. I have put condensed versions below.

Output from `java -Djavax.net.debug=ssl` (Server)

```
`System property jdk.tls.client.cipherSuites is set to 'null'
System property jdk.tls.server.cipherSuites is set to 'null'
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5
***
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Inaccessible trust store: thekeystore.jks
trustStore is: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/security/cacerts
trustStore type is: pkcs12
trustStore provider is: 
the last modified time is: Wed Jun 27 20:03:48 CDT 2018
Reload the trust store
Reload trust certs
Reloaded 104 trust certs
adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=Equifax Secure Global eBusiness CA-1, O=Equifax Secure Inc., C=US
  Issuer:  CN=Equifax Secure Global eBusiness CA-1, O=Equifax Secure Inc., C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0xc3517
  Valid from Sun Jun 20 23:00:00 CDT 1999 until Sun Jun 21 23:00:00 CDT 2020

**

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=DigiCert Global Root G2, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
  Issuer:  CN=DigiCert Global Root G2, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x33af1e6a711a9a0bb2864b11d09fae5
  Valid from Thu Aug 01 07:00:00 CDT 2013 until Fri Jan 15 06:00:00 CST 2038

keyStore is : 
keyStore type is : pkcs12
keyStore provider is : 
init keystore
init keymanager of type SunX509
trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for TLSv1
**
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Thread-0, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 238
check handshake state: client_hello[1]
update handshake state: client_hello[1]
upcoming handshake states: server_hello[2]
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  random_bytes = {D0 88 D8 B1 E4 B5 51 EF E4 1F B4 3F FD E9 92 E5 B8 8E DA 06 7C 24 27 19 4F FF 59 99 9F 3D F1 E3}
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension supported_groups, group names: {secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp256k1, ffdhe2048, ffdhe3072, ffdhe4096, ffdhe6144, ffdhe8192}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA256withDSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA224withDSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA
Extension extended_master_secret
Extension status_request_v2
CertStatusReqItemV2: ocsp_multi, OCSPStatusRequest
    ResponderIds: <EMPTY>
    Extensions: <EMPTY>
CertStatusReqItemV2: ocsp, OCSPStatusRequest
    ResponderIds: <EMPTY>
    Extensions: <EMPTY>
Extension status_request: ocsp, OCSPStatusRequest
    ResponderIds: <EMPTY>
    Extensions: <EMPTY>
***
%% Initialized:  [Session-2, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL]
%% Invalidated:  [Session-2, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL]
Thread-0, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = handshake_failure
Thread-0, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
Thread-0, called closeSocket()
Thread-0, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common
New Connection Established From/127.0.0.1`
```

Output from `java -Djavax.net.debug=ssl` (client)

```
`System property jdk.tls.client.cipherSuites is set to 'null'
System property jdk.tls.server.cipherSuites is set to 'null'
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
**
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Inaccessible trust store: thekeystore.jks
trustStore is: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/security/cacerts
trustStore type is: pkcs12
trustStore provider is: 
the last modified time is: Wed Jun 27 20:03:48 CDT 2018
Reload the trust store
Reload trust certs
Reloaded 104 trust certs
adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=Equifax Secure Global eBusiness CA-1, O=Equifax Secure Inc., C=US
  Issuer:  CN=Equifax Secure Global eBusiness CA-1, O=Equifax Secure Inc., C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0xc3517
  Valid from Sun Jun 20 23:00:00 CDT 1999 until Sun Jun 21 23:00:00 CDT 2020
**
adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=DigiCert Global Root G2, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
  Issuer:  CN=DigiCert Global Root G2, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x33af1e6a711a9a0bb2864b11d09fae5
  Valid from Thu Aug 01 07:00:00 CDT 2013 until Fri Jan 15 06:00:00 CST 2038

keyStore is : 
keyStore type is : pkcs12
keyStore provider is : 
init keystore
init keymanager of type SunX509
trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for TLSv1
**
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
%% No cached client session
update handshake state: client_hello[1]
upcoming handshake states: server_hello[2]
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  random_bytes = {D0 88 D8 B1 E4 B5 51 EF E4 1F B4 3F FD E9 92 E5 B8 8E DA 06 7C 24 27 19 4F FF 59 99 9F 3D F1 E3}
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension supported_groups, group names: {secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp256k1, ffdhe2048, ffdhe3072, ffdhe4096, ffdhe6144, ffdhe8192}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA256withDSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA224withDSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA
Extension extended_master_secret
Extension status_request_v2
CertStatusReqItemV2: ocsp_multi, OCSPStatusRequest
    ResponderIds: <EMPTY>
    Extensions: <EMPTY>
CertStatusReqItemV2: ocsp, OCSPStatusRequest
    ResponderIds: <EMPTY>
    Extensions: <EMPTY>
Extension status_request: ocsp, OCSPStatusRequest
    ResponderIds: <EMPTY>
    Extensions: <EMPTY>
***
AWT-EventQueue-0, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 238
AWT-EventQueue-0, READ: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
AWT-EventQueue-0, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
AWT-EventQueue-0, called closeSocket()
AWT-EventQueue-0, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure`
```

I do not understand the issue I am having. The code can be found in this other post. [SSLServerSocket and certificate setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53323855/sslserversocket-and-certificate-setup/53325115?noredirect=1#comment93531191_53325115)

I've tried creating a certificate with the `keytool` application.

Comment: "no cipher suites in common": client and server configurations are done in such a way that they do not find a common algorithm that both accepts to use, hence no way to establish the communication. You will need to assess both configurations and compare them.

Comment: Answered on original.

Comment: The server doesn't have a KeyStore, so it doesn't have a private key, so the only cipher suites it can use are the insecure non-authenticating ones, and these are disabled or not enabled by the client, so there are no cipher suites available to the server.

Answer (score 2):

```
Inaccessible trust store: thekeystore.jks
```

If your truststore is placed in your classpath then you need to load the Truststore in Code because javax.net.ssl.trustStore does not support loading files in your classpath.
Unfortunatly this information is not docummented.

Comment: If that was the problem there wouldn't be any 'adding as trusted cert' messages, and there are, at both ends.

Comment: From the global trust store yes but not from thekeystore.jks

Comment: Andi is right: The custom keystore `thekeystore.jks` is not available/accessible. This yields to subsequent errors.