# SSL Handshake with PrivateKey Clarification

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, pfx

i think i have an error on my understanding on the SSL handshake, but do i?

My application cant verify itself on the api. After some digging with wireshark i noticed that theres no "certificate verify" step and my private key certificate is not signed with one of the trusted authorities so my first thought was that.
The catch is: If i add the same certificate to my browser(firefox) and call the API i get a popup for the certificate selection and it actually works.

Isnt it supposed to only accept certificates that are listed under the  Distinguished Names? Or is this only required for the public key and the private not necessarily?
What does firefox actually do in background when the popup comes, create a custom certificate chain?

Setup is as followed:

- API is under https:somerandomurl
- API-Server integrated a certificate of ours for auth (for all i know)
  (this cert is actually a cert for https:someotherurl)
- Client has truststore with cert for somerandomurl
- Client has keystore with PKCS#12 cert

My guess is that my application has wrong/no certificate chain because as far as i know the PKCS#12 cert contains a pub and a private key BUT the pub is not for "somerandomurl" but "someotherurl". But thats just a guess, maybe its just the trusted auths

Comment: Your client certifiate should be signed by a globally certified CA. If not, it has to be added in the trust store of the server and vice versa. Does this help - https://stackoverflow.com/a/53325115/1235935? Also the root domain must be correctly mentioned in the certificate to my understanding. With the help of the code in the link, you might want to fiddle around and see

Comment: thanks for the link - had some background infos i didnt know yet. Sadly i dont have access to the server and the client code logic is basically the same.
Will try again after the CA was added