# Why does a Java SSL Connection still use the same cipher for the same client and server sockets?

Tags: java, ssl, encryption, handshake

I heard one friend say:

> For every SSL Connection in Java - when you look at the SSL debug - you can see the list of ciphers available during the handshake process, and that one is chosen.

I heard another friend say:

> For the same client and server SSL Sockets in Java - they will always choose the same cipher.

That to me seemed incongruent. How could you handshake with a list of ciphers and still come up with the same cipher every time?

So I wrote some code to test it - and it seemed that for 1000 connections for the same server and client - it will always choose the same cipher. Why?

```
import javax.net.ssl.*;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.EOFException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class SSLServerClient {

    private static Set<String> cipherNames = new HashSet();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "/path/KeyStore.jks");

        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "/path/KeyStore.jks");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "password");


        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {


            SSLServerSocketFactory sslserversocketfactory = (SSLServerSocketFactory) SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();

            SSLServerSocket serverListeningSSLSocket = (SSLServerSocket) sslserversocketfactory.createServerSocket(4380);

            SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
            SSLSocket clientSocket = (SSLSocket) sslSocketFactory.createSocket(serverListeningSSLSocket.getInetAddress(),
                    serverListeningSSLSocket.getLocalPort());

            SSLSocket serverCommsSSLSocket = (SSLSocket) serverListeningSSLSocket.accept();

            final byte[] bytes = "--Hello World!".getBytes();
            final OutputStream out = clientSocket.getOutputStream();


            final DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(serverCommsSSLSocket.getInputStream());

            (new Thread() {
                public void run() {

                    int len = 0;
                    try {
                        len = in.read();
                        final byte[] b = new byte[len];
                        in.readFully(b);
                        //System.out.println(new String(b));

                    } catch (SSLException | EOFException | SocketException | NegativeArraySizeException  e) {
                        // skip this one
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }).start();


            out.write(bytes.length);
            out.write(bytes);

            //System.out.println("protocol: "+ clientSocket.getSession().getProtocol());
            //System.out.println("cipher: " + clientSocket.getSession().getCipherSuite());
            cipherNames.add(clientSocket.getSession().getCipherSuite());

            clientSocket.close();
            serverCommsSSLSocket.close();
            serverListeningSSLSocket.close();
        }
        System.out.println("Ciphers used: " + cipherNames);
    }
}
```

And the output is:

```
Ciphers used: [TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256]
```

Ie the same cipher 1000 times.

My question is: **Why does a Java SSL Connection still use the same cipher for the same client and server sockets?**

Comment: AFAIK, the cypher is negotiated between client and server. If you use the same client and server, why would it change ?

Comment: On top of @Thilo answer, have a look at this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/53325115/1235935

Answer (score 3):

The handshake chooses the best available cipher, depending on some algorithm that is entirely deterministic. For the same input (i.e. the same ciphers and versions declared to be available by both parties and whatever else goes into consideration) it will pick the same cipher.

Assuming that the choice is the objectively best one, there is no point to randomly pick another (i.e. inferior) cipher. In fact that would be a bad idea.

Disable TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 in your client (or provide something better) and you will get something else.